# How to connect data from Data Lake Gen 1 to Tableau

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I would like to connect data from 'Data Lake Storage Gen 1 account' to Tableau. What tableau version is recommended for Gen 1 connection?

PS: I am aware Gen 2 can be connected to Tableau 2021.1

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau document doesn't talked about which version is recommended for Gen 1 connection, but is also provide a way to connect to Data Lake Storage Gen 1 account.

You can ref this document: [Visualize Live Azure Data Lake Storage Data in Tableau](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/azuredatalake-tableau-desktop.rst#Authenticating-to-a-Gen-1-DataLakeStore-Account_ylt79wig7):

Authenticating to a Gen 1 DataLakeStore Account

Gen 1 uses OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD for authentication.

For this, an Active Directory web application is required. You can create one as follows:

1. Sign in to your Azure Account through the .
2. Select "Azure Active Directory".
3. Select "App registrations".
4. Select "New application registration".
5. Provide a name and URL for the application. Select Web app for the
   type of application you want to create.
6. Select "Required permissions" and change the required permissions
   for this app. At a minimum, "Azure Data Lake" and "Windows Azure
   Service Management API" are required.
7. Select "Key" and generate a new key. Add a description, a duration,
   and take note of the generated key. You won't be able to see it
   again.

To authenticate against a Gen 1 DataLakeStore account, the following properties are required:

- **Schema:** Set this to **ADLSGen1**.
- **Account**: Set this to the name of the account.
- **OAuthClientId**: Set this to the application Id of the app you created.
- **OAuthClientSecret**: Set this to the key generated for the app you
  created.
- **TenantId**: Set this to the tenant Id. See the property for more
  information on how to acquire this.
- **Directory**: Set this to the path which will be used to store the
  replicated file. If not specified, the root directory will be used.